# SQLAlchemy: One-Way Relationship, Correlated Subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

thanks in advance for your help.

I have two entities, Human and Chimp. Each has a collection of metrics, which can contain subclasses of a MetricBlock, for instance CompleteBloodCount (with fields WHITE_CELLS, RED_CELLS, PLATELETS).

So my object model looks like (forgive the ASCII art):

```
---------   metrics    ---------------      ----------------------
| Human | ---------->  | MetricBlock | <|-- | CompleteBloodCount |
---------              ---------------      ----------------------
                        ^
---------    metrics    |
| Chimp | --------------
---------
```

This is implemented with the following tables:

```
Chimp (id, …)
Human (id, …)

MetricBlock (id, dtype)
CompleteBloodCount (id, white_cells, red_cells, platelets)
CholesterolCount (id, hdl, ldl)

ChimpToMetricBlock(chimp_id, metric_block_id)
HumanToMetricBlock(human_id, metric_block_id)
```

So a human knows its metric blocks, but a metric block does not know its human or chimp.

I would like to write a query in SQLAlchemy to find all CompleteBloodCounts for a particular human. In  SQL I could write something like:

```
SELECT cbc.id
FROM complete_blood_count cbc
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM human h
       INNER JOIN human_to_metric_block h_to_m on h.id = h_to_m.human_id
   WHERE
       h_to_m.metric_block_id = cbc.id
)
```

I'm struggling though to write this in SQLAlchemy. I believe correlate(), any(), or an aliased join may be helpful, but the fact that a MetricBlock doesn't know its Human or Chimp is a stumbling block for me.

Does anyone have any advice on how to write this query? Alternately, are there other strategies to define the model in a way that works better with SQLAlchemy?

Thank you for your assistance.

```
Python 2.6
SQLAlchemy 0.7.4
Oracle 11g
```

Edit:

HumanToMetricBlock is defined as:

```
humanToMetricBlock = Table(
    "human_to_metric_block",
    metadata,
    Column("human_id", Integer, ForeignKey("human.id"),
    Column("metric_block_id", Integer, ForeginKey("metric_block.id")
)
```

[per the manual](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each primate should have a unique ID, regardless of what type of primate they are. I'm not sure why each set of attributes (MB, CBC, CC) are separate tables, but I assume that they have more than one dimension (primate) such as time, otherwise I would only have one giant table.

Thus, I would structure this problem in the following manner:
Create a parent object Primate and derive humans and chimps from it. This example is using single table inheritance, though you may want to use joined table inheritance based on their attributes.

```
class Primate(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'primate'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    genus = Column(String)
    ...attributes all primates have...
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': genus, 'polymorphic_identity': 'primate'}

class Chimp(Primate):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'chimp'}
    ...attributes...

class Human(Primate):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'human'}
    ...attributes...

class MetricBlock(Base):
    id = ...
```

Then you create a single many-to-many table (you can use an association proxy instead):

```
class PrimateToMetricBlock(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) # primary key is needed!
    primate_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('primate.id'))
    primate = relationship('Primate') # If you care for relationships. 
    metricblock_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('metric_block.id')
    metricblock = relationship('MetricBlock')
```

Then I would structure the query like so (note that the on clause is not necessary since SQLAlchemy can infer the relationships automatically since there's no ambiguity):

```
query = DBSession.query(CompleteBloodCount).\
    join(PrimateToMetricBlock, PrimateToMetricBlock.metricblock_id == MetricBlock.id)
```

If you want to filter by primate type, join the Primate table and filter:

```
query = query.join(Primate, Primate.id == PrimateToMetricBlock.primate_id).\
    filter(Primate.genus == 'human')
```

Otherwise, if you know the ID of the primate (primate_id), no additional join is necessary:

```
query = query.filter(PrimateToMetricBlock.primate_id == primate_id)
```

If you're only retrieving one object, end the query with:

```
return query.first()
```

Otherwise:

```
return query.all()
```

Forming your model like this should eliminate any confusion and actually make everything simpler. If I'm missing something, let me know.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you for your quick reply. I edited the post with my model definition for the many-to-many join table, and I wonder if you could please clarify your post in light of the mapping? I wasn't aware I could actually refer to this table. Thanks again.

Comment: Asked a different way, is there a way to use only human.metrics? I have either a human or a chimp and I'd like the CBC's, and I think I'd need a lookup in python to find the join table. I apologize for not asking this better in the post; my question and your function name assume human only.

Comment: ah, i think i found a better way to do do this problem. let me edit the answer.